# Create nested environment (with tabular)?

Tags: tables, environments

I create two environments that contains `tabular : partitiondanse` and nested mesure but i get an error at compilation time:

> ```
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
> <template> \unskip \hfil }
>                           \hskip \tabcolsep \hskip -.5\arrayrulewidth \vrule...
> l.17 \begin{mesure}
>                    {l}
> ```

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcounter{countpartition}
\newcounter{countmesure}

\newenvironment{partitiondanse}{%
  \setcounter{countmesure}{0}
  \addtocounter{countpartition}{1}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l}}{\end{tabular}}  

\newenvironment{mesure}{%
  \addtocounter{countmesure}{1}
  \thecountmesure & 
  \begin{tabular}}{\end{tabular}\\}
\begin{document}

\begin{partitiondanse}
\begin{mesure}{l}
1\\
\end{mesure}
\end{partitiondanse}

\end{document}
```

Can you help me fixing it ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is associated with your insertion of `\thecountmesure`, followed by `&`. This leaves `\begin{mesure}` in one group (the cell before `&`) and `\end{mesure}` in another (the cell after `&`).

Here is a workable solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{countmesure}

\newenvironment{partitiondanse}{%
  \setcounter{countmesure}{0}%
  \tabular{ >{\stepcounter{countmesure}\thecountmesure~\vrule} l }
}{%
  \endtabular
}

\newenvironment{mesure}[1]{%
  \tabular[t]{#1}
}{%
  \endtabular
}

\begin{document}

\begin{partitiondanse}
  \begin{mesure}{ l }
    abc \\ def
  \end{mesure} \\
  \begin{mesure}{ r }
    ghijkl \\ mnopq
  \end{mesure}
\end{partitiondanse}

\end{document}
```